# Can't install JDK

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio-2015

I am setting up a clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit. I first installed Office, then I installed Visual Studio 2015. Everything worked except for Java SE Development Kit 7.0.550.13. The message said "The installer failed. Unknown error -3". The only additional information given in the log file is "Process returned error: 0x80048646".

So I downloaded the latest Java SE Development Kit 8u74 from Oracle myself. But when I try to install it nothing happens. I researched the error and most of the suggestions had to do with accounts and permissions. This is not an issue because I am using the Administrator account, all permissions for all files and folders are set to Full Control, and there is no anti-virus.

When I double click the setup file it creates a folder in my temp directory called jds*.tmp, where the * is a number that varies. Within that folder it creates a file jds*.tmp, where the * is again a number. After a short time this file disappears and is replaced by a file with the same name as the setup file, but with a slightly different size. The setup file is called jdk-8u74-windows-i586 and is 190,853,720 bytes long. The file in the temp directory with the same name is 190,569,048 bytes. After another short time the JDK process terminates and the temp files and folders are deleted. I managed to save the temp file before it got deleted and tried to run it directly but it also does nothing, albeit more quickly because it terminates right away.

I tested the installer on a clean install virtual machine and it behaved the same way at the start. But then instead of terminating, the temp file started running as a separate process, and after another short time the Windows installer started. This led to the Java install window. That gave me the idea to make sure the Windows installer service was running or that it might be an installer problem, but that didn't help either.

I'm not sure if my problem with installing JDK is a result of the Visual Studio failure or if it is something else. It seems like it must be VS related because this was an otherwise clean install of Windows and the installer does work on a clean virtual machine.

Any ideas how to can get this to work?

Comment: may be some screenshots can help to understand your problem.

Comment: A screenshot would show a blank screen. Double clicking the setup file does nothing. The rest of the information I had to piece together myself from task manager and whatnot.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

Well without really understanding what's going on I managed to get it to install. I believe the main JDK executable is a wrapper that installs other setup files, like the one I mentioned in the temp directory. That exe in turn installs some .msi files. What I did was took my VM machine, ran the JDK installer, and copied the .msi and .cab files from C:\Users\\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jdk1.8.0_74 to the same folder in the problem machine. I then ran the .msi file directly and it worked. And it only took me 4 days of work... fantastic. From other research I did I have a feeling that the problem in the installer wrapper creates the files in one folder then tries to run them in another. But I haven't verified this speculation.