# Installing JDK on a second drive

Tags: java, windows

I am in a situation where I need to install jdk8 on Windows. The C Drive is full and due to circumstances beyond my control I need to install JDK on the E drive. However when I run the JDK installer nothing appears to happen. Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/426068), I am guessing the installer is trying to create the jdk_combo directory on the C Drive, which is likely impossible. Is there any alternate method of installing the JDK or a solution that will allow me to use the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to run the jdk installer on another machine and then get the MSI from the AppData folder got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902657/2801159).

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the JDK in any drive (suppose `H:\Java_RE`)
2. Then go to, `This PC` >> `Properties` >> `Advance system settings` >> `Environment variable` >> `System variables` >> `Path`
3. Click `Edit`
4. Click `New`
5. Browse the path (ex: `H:\Java_RE\bin`)
6. Click `Ok`.

Answer (score 0):

I Have faced a similar issue while installing java on my D drive. Later I found that it was due to the previous path existing in the environment variables. Check for any previous JDK or ORACLE paths existing in environment variables. In my case, I have deleted the below path it worked for me.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath.